# Do not display points above diagonal in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r

I have created the following data set

```
p_cd = c(0.01, 0.15, 0.30, 0.50, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 0.99)
p_bm = c(0.01, 0.15, 0.30, 0.50, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 0.99)
data = as.data.frame(expand.grid(p_cd,p_bm))
data = cbind(data,rep(NA,dim(data)[1]))
weights = c(NA,0.48,0.28,0.1,0.03,0.02,0.013,0.01,NA,NA,1.52,0.57,0.18,0.1,0.07,0.07,NA,NA,NA,1.8,0.57,0.35,0.25,0.24,NA,NA,NA,NA,2.21,1.26,0.91,0.86,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3.62,2.62,2.5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,5.25,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,24.46,rep(NA,8))
u = 1
for(i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
  if(data[i,1]>data[i,2]){
    data[i,3] = weights[u]
    u = u + 1
  }
}
```

Based on that data set I create the following plot in `ggplot2` in `R`

```
p_1 = ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = subset(data), aes(x=p_cd, y=p_bm, col = weights), size = 3) +
  scale_color_continuous(type = "viridis") +
  geom_point(data = subset(data, weights <= 1), aes(x=p_cd, y=p_bm), color = "black", size = 3) +
  xlim(0, 1) + ylim(0,1) +
  ggtitle("N = 50 & K = 2") + labs(colour = "Root Mean Square Error")
```

However my goal is to plot only the points that are under the diagonal, i.e. all the points (the color points this this case) for which we have that `data[i,1]>data[i,2]`. How is this possible to be done in `R`?

Comment: The simplest solution is to `filter` your data so that only those points are included.

Comment: @mhovd You are damn right! Thank you!